# Closing resources with dependency injection

Tags: python, resources, resource-management

I have the following pseudocode:

```
class Resource:
    """E.g. Session, connection, file, etc."""
    async def open(self):
        pass
    async def close(self):
        pass

class ResourceUser:
    def __init__(self, resource: Resource):
        self.resource = resource

async def main():
    r = Resource(...)  # Plenty of those
    await r.open(...)
    # More resource initialization
    try:
        ResourceUser(r, r2, r3)
    finally:
        await r.close(...) # In practice done with AsyncExitStack
        await r.close(...)
```

Main is a large function, and I would like to extract the creation of resources and ResourceUser:

```
async def create_user():
    r, r2, r3, ... = Resource(), ...
    await r.open()
    return ResourceUser(r)
```

By doing so, I lose the option to close the resources correctly.

An optional way to solve it is by creating a close() function in ResourceUser:

```
async def close(self):
    await self.resource.close()
```

Unfortunately, this assumes that the ResourceUser "owns" the given resources, and has many potential drawbacks such as preventing the sharing of resources (like a connection pool) between multiple instances.

Counting on the `__del__` (akin to RAII) is not an option, especially considering the asynchronous nature of the closing method.

Initializing the resources in a different function and then creating the User in main() will result in plenty of different resources in the return statement, which is rather ugly. Monkey-packing the `ResourceUser.close()` is also pretty ugly.

Is there any standardized way that does not over-complicate yet achieve the desired result?

Comment: Can you use [async context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.asynccontextmanager) ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely in what way? You mean by creating the initialization, yielding the created resource, and closing everything afterwards? That's kinda smart, I like that solution

Comment: I've posted a pseudo code how you can use async context manager here. If it's ok, you can accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pseudo-code how you can handle this with `contextlib.asynccontextmanager`

```py
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager


class Resource:
    """E.g. Session, connection, file, etc."""

    async def open(self):
        pass

    async def close(self):
        pass


class ResourceUser:
    def __init__(self, resource: Resource, ...):
        self.resource = resource


@asynccontextmanager
async def get_resource_user():
    r1 = Resource(...)  # Plenty of those
    r2 = Resource(...)  # Plenty of those
    try:
        await r1.open(...)  # better use asynccontextmanager for this too, to not call close() explicitly
        await r2.open(...)
        yield ResourceUser(r1, r2)

    finally:
        await r1.close(...)
        await r2.close(...)


async def main():

    async with get_resource_user() as user:
        # do stuff with `user`

    # resources are closed automatically at this point
```